protobuf: when should I used parenthesis around identifiers in options
It is possible to put parenthesis around identifiers in options, as documented in https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/proto3-spec/#option
e.g. you can write
option foo.bar.baz = 1;

and also
option (foo.bar.baz) = 1;

or
option (foo.bar).baz = 1;

What's the difference between them? Why do we need parenthesis in the grammar?

The use of parens syntax is to designate between builtin options (provided by Protobuf/protoc directly), and custom options defined by external parties. More info on Custom Options here: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto2/#customoptions
Now, with custom options, there's a specific meaning to
option (foo.bar.baz) = 1;

vs
option (foo.bar).baz = 1;

In the first example, you're setting the value of an extension field directly (a scalar field). In the second example, you're setting a field of a sub-message.
If that's not totally clear, the link above has some great examples of what I'm referring to.

Got it! Thanks! I think proto3 documentation didn't mention this syntax (it only provided a link to the proto2 doc). That's why I didn't find the documentation in the beginning.

ah yes, this is because these options are powered by extensions, which is largely a proto2 feature. Even though you can consume them in proto3 files!
